# What does allocs/op and B/op mean in go benchmark?

Tags: go, benchmarking

When I run my benchmarks with `go test -v -bench=. -benchmem`, I see the following results.

```
f1     10000        120860 ns/op        2433 B/op         28 allocs/op
f2     10000        120288 ns/op        2288 B/op         26 allocs/op
```

Based on my understanding:

1. `10000` is the number of iterations `for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {`.
2. `XXX ns/op` is approximate time it took for one iteration to complete

But even after [reading the docs](https://golang.org/pkg/testing/), I can not find out what `B/op` and `allocs/op` mean.

---

My guess is that allocs/op has something to do with garbage collection and memory allocation (the less the better).

Can anyone give a nice explanation of the meaning of these values. Also it would be nice to know why do the go up and main steps to reduce them (I realize this is test specific, but may be there are some universal hints that work in many cases)

Answer (score 67, accepted):

`allocs/op` means how many distinct memory allocations occurred per op (single iteration).

`B/op` is how many bytes were allocated per op.

Comment: Is that B/op the allocations, made in stake frame or in heap? Or is it what the memory amount that GO GC has to clean?

Comment: Is there a formal documentation to explain these metrics?

Comment: What does `memory allocation` mean? Does that mean `set a value for a variable`?

Comment: @RyanLv: No, it means memory was _allocated_, not modified. Setting a value for a variable just modifies the contents of pre-allocated memory.

Comment: @RyanLv memory allocation means getting more memory from the operating system. Doing so reduces the available memory to your and other programs in your system.

Answer (score 2):

A quick dig into the "testing/benchmark.go" source, shows that:

```golang
// AllocsPerOp returns the "allocs/op" metric,
// which is calculated as r.MemAllocs / r.N.
func (r BenchmarkResult) AllocsPerOp() int64
```

What's r.MemAllocs then?

```golang
type BenchmarkResult struct {
    MemAllocs uint64        // The total number of memory allocations.
    MemBytes  uint64        // The total number of bytes allocated.
    // ...
}
```

How does the "total number" is accumulated?

```golang
// file: testing/allocs.go

func AllocsPerRun(runs int, f func()) (avg float64) {
    // ...

    // Measure the starting statistics
    var memstats runtime.MemStats
    runtime.ReadMemStats(&memstats)
    mallocs := 0 - memstats.Mallocs

    // Run the function the specified number of times
    for i := 0; i < runs; i++ {
        f()
    }

    // Read the final statistics
    runtime.ReadMemStats(&memstats)
    mallocs += memstats.Mallocs

    // ...
    return float64(mallocs / uint64(runs))
```

So now we know that whatever is runtime.Memstats.Mallocs, is the "alloc" in "alloc/ops". Here is the Memstate:

```golang
// file: runtime.mstats.go

type MemStats struct {
    // ...
    // Mallocs is the cumulative count of heap objects allocated.
    // The number of live objects is Mallocs - Frees.
    Mallocs uint64
    // ...
}
```